# Having some problems trying to put views in the right places

Tags: layout, tablelayout, gravity

I'm generating dynamic tablerows in this XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:scrollbars="none" >

    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/layoutPrincipal1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:stretchColumns="1">

    </TableLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

The problem is: I would like to have some views in a specific position using gravity, but when a define for example, button1.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL)); it doesn't work, but if I do this directly in the xml It works(with layout_gravity), someone knows what to do?